# How to show more results in autocomplete suggestions with scroll

Tags: android, google-places-api

I recently used to `google place autocomplete API`, and it works fine. But when I type something in the search bar, only 5 results are shown. How can I show more results, with the dropdown of suggestions scrollable, not taking the whole screen?

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results)
Google Autocomplete API supports results only upto 5.

> A JSON response contains two root elements:
>    The Places API returns up to 5 results.
>
> An XML response consists of a single  element with two types of child elements: The Places API returns up to 5 results.

Comment: Oh. thanks. And we style the dropdown as per our needs I guess that can be done?

Comment: you should change parameters and get different results and build a large array by adding all the results

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation the results of your serach are returned in a `JSON response`, which contains 2 root elements, `status` and `predictions`, it seems that `predictions` are limited by 5 results:

> predictions contains an array of places, with information about the
>   place. See Place Autocomplete Results for information about these
>   results. The Places API returns up to 5 results.